# Docker Nginx прокинуть директорию

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Закипаю кошмар. Пытаюсь использовать докер на винде(учусь). Вот так выглядит docker-compose

```
    # Версия docker-compose
version: '2'
# Список наших сервисов (контейнеров)
services:
    nginx:
        # используем последний стабильный образ nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        # маршрутизируем порты
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        # монтируем директории, слева директории на основной машине, справа - куда они монтируются в контейнере
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/hosts:/nginx/hosts
            - ./nginx/www:/nginx/www
            - ./nginx/logs:/nginx/logs
```

Я не могу понять как настраивать конфигурационный файл nginx и куда ложить файлы проекта что бы потом пересобирать образ, судя по коментам, слева то что локлаьно, справа то что в образе, но не пашет. Нифига не понимаю, помогите понять.

Answer (score 2):

Начать предлагаю со следующей конфигурации

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Запускаем

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Подключаемся к командной строке контейнера

```
docker-compose exec nginx bash
```

Там можем посмотреть файл конфигурации nginx

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Тоже самое можно сделать напрямую

```
docker-compose exec nginx cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Строчка

```
root        /app/web/;
```

говорит, то nginx "отдает" файлы из директории контейнера `/app/web`

Т.е. именно в эту директорию нам нужно подмонтировать статику нашего проекта

Получаем конфигурацию:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes: 
     - ./nginx/my.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
     - ./app:/app/web
```

Где `./app` - папка со статикой нашего проекта,
`./nginx/my.conf` - файл с конфигурацией для nginx